# attach eventListener only on document.ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

is there any way to attach an event to document.ready? for example take a look at this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').load('eg_pageload.html');

    $(document).ajaxStart(function(){
        console.log('say something to the console');
    });

    $('#trigger').on('click', function(){
        $('body').load('file.txt');
    });
});
```

so, when user click on `#trigger` the ajaxStart did not activated. in other words that ajaxStart should only triggered when another ajax request is start while page loading, otherwise don't start the ajaxRequest. i tried to unbind the ajaxRequest on ajaxComplete function, but it doesn't work because somepage at my site don't call any ajax request at page loading, instead it's call ajax request on click event for example.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you only want to execute the the `ajaxStart` callback for Ajax called initiated *ebefore* the document is ready?

Comment: I don't get it at all, only fire ajaxStart on requests that are done during pageload, but you don't have any ajax requests on pageload ?

Comment: on my actual code there is ajax call on page load, that's just for example. should i paste my actual code?

Comment: You might look into `global:false` option of `$.ajax({ global: false, ...})`

Comment: When you install the `.ajaxStart()` handler inside the `document.ready()` callback, you're guaranteeing that it is NOT installed before `document.ready()`, but you seem to want it in force before `document.ready()`.  You will either need to make your ajax calls wait until `.ready()` or install the `.ajaxStart()` handler sooner if you want the two to see each other.

Comment: Reading your question a couple more times, now I'm unsure what you're really trying to do because several of your phrases are contradictory.  Please try to clarify what you're trying to do.

Comment: ok, so in my web page there is some page that call ajax on page load also there is ajax call that initiate by clicking on some element..i want to prevent the `ajaxStart` from being triggered if ajax was triggered by `click` event. does that make sense?

Comment: @Dariel Pratama see my answer as it covers what you are wanting to do. Mixing it with the `click` event globally is not really feasible though.

Comment: yes @MattGreen i am trying what you said in your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand right you are wanting to disable the `AjaxStart` from trigger on specific `Ajax` calls. This is typically done like so:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "test.html",
    global: false,
    ...
});
```

Note the `global: false,` line. This is exactly what it is used for.

From AjaxStart [Docs](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/)

> Additional Notes:
>
> If $.ajax() or $.ajaxSetup() is called with the global option set to
>   false, the .ajaxStart() method will not fire.

From Ajax [Docs](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Ajax/)

> global (default: true) Type: Boolean Whether to trigger global Ajax
>   event handlers for this request. The default is true. Set to false to
>   prevent the global handlers like ajaxStart or ajaxStop from being
>   triggered. This can be used to control various Ajax Events.

You are using the `.load()` method however so that option is not available. It is not available with the similar `.get()` method, but those are both short-hand Ajax functions so you can just use `Ajax` like so.

```
$(document).ready(function()
    $(document).ajaxStart(function(){
        console.log('say something to the console');
    });

    $('#trigger').on('click', function(){
       $.ajax({
          url: 'file.txt',
          global: false,
          dataType: 'html'
       });
       .done(function( html ) {
           $( 'body' ).append( html );
       });
    });
});
```

This is going to be the only way to avoid the `AjaxStart` on that request and it will not matter where in the `DOM` load it takes place.

The above `Jquery` is an example, so their may be minor mistakes, but the links provided will cover the process in full.

Comment: thanks, it's working. though i change some part of this question to match my needs :D

Answer (score 0):

How about using *unbind*:

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').load('eg_pageload.html');

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
    console.log('say something to the console');
});

$('#trigger').on('click', function(){
    $('body').unbind("ready"); // Add this line
    $('body').load('file.txt');
});
```

});

Comment: Wouldn't this cause the `AjaxStart` to not be called on subsequent `Ajax` requests where it is intended to be used?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `on()` and `off()`, it's just an event?

Internally jQuery does `$(document).on('ajaxStart', fn)` so you can remove it with `off()`, and that means you can bind the event at the top of the callback for `ready`, and just unbind it at the end off the callback, and it won't get called for ajax triggered by later events

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('ajaxStart', ajaxFN); // place at start

    function ajaxFN(){
        console.log('say something to the console');
    }

    $('body').load('eg_pageload.html'); // this will trigger ajaxStart

    $('#trigger').on('click', function(){
        $('body').load('file.txt');     // this will NOT
    });

    $(document).off('ajaxStart', ajaxFN); // place at end
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/mFScX/7/)